# Change filstream directory permissions using T-SQL?

Tags: c#, sql-server, unit-testing, filestream

Using `SQL Server 2012` with [filestreams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Consider this `SQL` script:

```
CREATE DATABASE [Test]
GO

ALTER DATABASE [Test] ADD FILEGROUP [FileStream] CONTAINS FILESTREAM
GO

ALTER DATABASE [Test] ADD FILE (
    NAME = 'Test_FileStream',
    FILENAME = 'C:\Data')
    TO FILEGROUP [FileStream]
GO
```

Obviously, the `C:\Data` folder is created by `SQL Server`. Hence, the owner of this folder is the SQL Server account (usually `MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS`). My software requires **reading** filestreams directly, via the `NTFS` file system so I have set `FilestreamEffectiveLevel` to a value of 3. So, `SQL Server` need the right to **write** filestream data (obviously), and clients need the right to **read** filestream data.

Clients will be reading the data using [SqlFileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlfilestream.aspx):

```
using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
{
    var fileStreamData = GetFileStreamData();
    using (var stream = new SqlFileStream(
        fileStreamData.FilePath,
        fileStreamData.TransactionContext,
        FileAccess.Read,
        FileOptions.SequentialScan,
        0))
    {
        var data = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
}
```

Since my regular users need read access to the filestream data, the `C:\Data` folder must be readable by regular users. I can manually fix this by right-clicking the folder, **elevate**, and add necessary read permissions.

The problem is that I don't want this manual step! When I have run `CreateDatabase()` in my `C#` code, I want everything to be correctly configured. I tried this code, but it throws an `UnauthorizedAccessException`:

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Data");
var ds = di.GetAccessControl();
ds.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(
    @"Everyone",
    FileSystemRights.Read,
    AccessControlType.Allow));
di.SetAccessControl(ds);
```

Yes, if I *run my software elevated* it works. The problem is that the above code needs to be run in a unit test. In this case, elevating Visual Studio would render the outcome of the unit test useless! I do run my tests as administrator using [impersonation](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=306158), but non-elevated.

### Summary

- `SQL Server` creates a directory for filestream data.
- The directory is not readable by regular users.
- Regular users need read access to this directory.
- The read permissions need to be granted programmatically from a `Unit Test`.
- Unit tests are run as administrator impersonated, but non-elevated for obvious reasons.

### Question

How can I tell `SQL Server` to grant certain groups/users read access to the newly created filestream directory?

I can think of a couple of ideas:

1. Alter the permissions using some kind of `T-SQL` without the need for elevation.
2. Alter the permissions using `xp_cmdshell` without the need for elevation.
3. Run `C#` code on `SQL Server` that changes the permissions. Again, without elevation.

I'm sure `SQL Server` has the capability to set the permission since it actually owns the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, SQL Server does not expose the ability to change permissions on the directory storing filestream data using T-SQL. This feature would be *possible* since the SQL Server owns the directory, but it appears that it does not exist.

The reason your C# code cannot update file permissions without elevation is because your user account neither owns the directory nor has been granted the "Change Permissions" permission on it. The Administrators group does have the ability to change permissions, but you must elevate in order to use that group membership. Again, you have no way around this unless you want to disable UAC (not recommended) or mess with Local Security Policy (*very* not recommended).

Therefore, option 2 sounds like your best choice. `xp_cmdshell` would run your command as the SQL Server service account which owns the directory, so it should be able to change the ACL. You can use the `cacls` command to change permissions on the folder. You would probably want a command similar to this:

```
cacls "C:\Data" /e /g Users:r

    cacls      -- Change ACLs
    "C:\Data"  -- Directory to change
    /e         -- Edit the current ACL instad of replacing it
    /g Users:r -- Grant the "Users" group read-only access
```

See also: [`cacls` documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490872.aspx), [`xp_cmdshell` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! This approach *seems* to work. I successfully grant read access to 'Everyone'. However, of my two regular users the filestream is only accessible by one of them. Is it possible that some extra grant is needed in SQL Server? E.g. role/permission for user X?

Comment: In order to access filestream data through T-SQL, the user must have the appropriate access to the table (you can use the normal [GRANT command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187965.aspx)). Access to the underlying NTFS files is irrelevant.

Comment: Even if using SqlFileStream? SQL Server returns an UNC path to the file, and you read it using a stream. That UNC path bypasses any file/directory rights?

Comment: If you use the BeginRead, CopyTo, or Read methods on the SqlFileStream object, then you're using the SQL server to read the data, not reading it directly. If you're just using SqlFileStream object, you don't need to worry about the NTFS permissions. If you really are accessing the files directly from disk (maybe by using classes from System.IO), then you do, but I also think that is _very_ unusual.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that I needed `GRANT` on the actual table as all my queries go through stored procedures. `SqlFileStream` obviously makes direct calls to the table. This did the trick: `GRANT SELECT ON [dbo].[Image] TO [myrole]`